# What if I will not use Software Design Patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

What kind of problems may I face, if I won't use Software Design Patterns? Can you tell me about the problems of approaching the design using standard object-oriented techniques?

Comment: Quite a few Software Design Patterns are fairly obvious. You would have to know them all very well to be sure you aren't using them - probably well enough that you might as well use them!

Comment: As a side point to @JamesMcLeod, many "Design Patterns" are very obvious and things everyone would do anyway. Why do we give them names, then? For the purposes of communication. "I'm using the X pattern" has far greater semantic density than explaining your solution in the hopes the other end will go "Oh yeah! I've done that too, except I called my variables...".

Comment: I agree, one of the main reasons to know design patterns is for unambiguous communication. And some of them are obscure enough that a normal person probably wouldn't think of them. B ut it is far more important to be able to understand when to use something like the Flyweight Pattern than to know its name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Your question is pretty broad, so you might not get the advice you really need. Can you be more specific? For example, is there a particular pattern you're wondering about? Maybe you're curious about the balance between spending time designing a system and the time spent actually writing it?

Comment: Its actually fairly simple: If you don't write good code, then you don't get a good job.

Comment: @AJMansfield Some of the worst code I've seen involved overenthusiasm for design patterns.

Comment: @ErikReppen the blame for overuse of design patterns should be attributed to the person who does it. From my perspective, the core problem is not in design patterns itself, but over-generalization (partly due to lack of architectural oversight) and over-engineering (sometimes by committees-of-engineers).

Comment: Arguably to a great extent design patterns ARE the standard object oriented techniques - just in the form of thought out examples.  They're as easy to misuse as any other code feature in the hands of the poor developer.

Comment: "Design Patterns" is a lexicon, not a technique.

Comment: @ErikReppen: I call that Pattern Happiness Disease. Object Happiness Disease and Thread Happiness Disease are also common. It can be hard to get people to curb their enthusiasm.

Comment: @rwong I was just pointing out that design patterns are just ideas, not necessarily "good code" simply for having been implemented somewhere. They aren't all language agnostic for one.

Answer (score 76):

You're missing the point.

Design Patterns inherently exist when doing software design, just like structural patterns exist in the world. Even if you don't know the name of things, you'll eventually find that certain physical structures are well suited for certain problems. You'll find that a triangle shape of wood/metal bars/etc is a very stable structure, but only on a plane. You'll find square bricks have certain advantages over round ones...

Likewise, certain software structures are in some way unique or optimal. You'll eventually find them and use them regardless if you know the *names* for them. That's the core of what design patterns are - they're *names* for these structures that experienced programmers know and use anyways. It gives programmers the ability to communicate much more uniformly and succinctly. It also lets programmers think in the concept of patterns more consciously.

So the two key points I'm trying to make:

1. You can't *not* use design patterns.
2. By not knowing the names for the things you're using, you'll have a difficult time working in a team.

Comment: +1: Absolutely right. I started OO development before design patterns became known or popular. Yes we also invented things _like_ factories, singletons and something that, when you squinted at it in a bright light sort of looks like the Strategy pattern. The point is now that I know design patterns I know the the factories were OK but could have been done better, the Singletons were badly done and what _might_ have been a Strategy pattern would have been much better if it actually **had been** a Strategy pattern.

Comment: ... Learning about design patterns, and learning how to use them correctly saves you so much time, you're less likely to try reinventing the wheel, stops you from leading yourself down a road towards bad design and building bad solutions. Suck it up and learn the patterns, use them when they work for you, and don't use them when they won't.

Comment: And this sums up exactly my views on patterns. They're wonderful tools for communicating what you're doing with other people. You never build them *exactly* though because every problem is different. But they're a gist, a direction, and a rough set of guidelines to follow, and it makes it easy to explain to others what the heck you're doing.

Comment: +1 for the comparison to physical structures. I would add that it helps to build a house if you already know that a "truss" is a good structure to support the load of a roof, rather than experimenting and hoping that it doesn't collapse.

Answer (score 39):

**Those who cannot remember the past are condemned to repeat it.**

You will not face any specific problems other than the ones raised by your design. And in time you will end up using the patterns without being aware, you just spent time figuring them out by yourself. Knowing the patterns beforehand makes them easier to spot in the design and bear the major advantage that they are proven by a number of individuals.

Everything that's being developed today is based largely on previous knowledge, it would make no sense to ignore it. Imagine building a skyscraper today without knowing the problems faced by the people who built cathedrals some hundreds years ago.

Comment: "Every quote has an equal and opposite unquote."

"We must tear asunder the past if we are truly to deserve the future." (OK that one was Hitler so probably best to ignore it....)

Answer (score 21):

> What kind of problems may I face, if I won't use Software Design Patterns?

You'll have the problem of not being able to write any software.

Variables are a design pattern.

Methods are a design pattern.

Operators -- addition, subtraction, etc -- are a design pattern.

Statements are a design pattern.

Values are a design pattern.

References are a design pattern.

Expressions are a design pattern.

Classes are a design pattern.

...

**Everything you do in programming at all times is a design pattern**. Most of the time the pattern is so ingrained into your thinking that you've stopped thinking of it as "a design pattern". The things that you have to learn like "the singleton pattern" and so on are simply patterns that haven't (yet) been baked into whatever language you're using.

> Can you tell me about the problems of approaching the design using standard object-oriented techniques?

No. I have no idea what this question means. Design patterns *are* "standard object-oriented techniques" -- that's what makes them *design patterns*. A design pattern is a standard technique for solving a particular problem, particularly (though not *necessarily*) in an object-oriented language.

Comment: `The things that you have to learn like "the singleton pattern" and so on are simply patterns that haven't (yet) been baked into whatever language you're using.` - That's (almost) the definition of a design pattern - a flexible/easily-reusable code construct used to overcome a limitation in the language itself, that is easy to communicate to others.  Once it's part of the language, it's no longer a design pattern.

Comment: @Izkata: So your position is that, say, the observer pattern is impossible in C# because C# has the observer pattern built into the language in the form of events? That's silly. The language-specific bit that is relevant to a pattern is the canonical way to implement the pattern in the language. Of course design patterns can be used in languages that support them directly; that's the whole point of supporting them directly!

Comment: I _never_ said impossible, I was trying to imply _unnecessary_.  [Java, for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#Example), does not have events so it uses the design pattern to simulate them.

Comment: @Izkata: I'm confused then. You said that once a pattern is part of the language it is no longer a pattern. So is 
"the observer pattern" a pattern *in Java* but *not* a pattern in C#?

Comment: I think [this section of the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Criticism) better describes what I was trying to get at.

Comment: @Izkata: I agree with the somewhat obvious point that descriptions of canonical implementation techniques for design patterns are common in languages which lack a built-in implementation for that pattern, but I see nothing in that section which supports your assertion that once a pattern is baked into a language, it is not a pattern anymore.

Comment: Or to put it another way, a design pattern is anything a programmer does, than can be described in English. I'm not sure I entirely agree with the definition, but I think it accurately reflects what you're saying and at least has the benefit of no subjective judgement what counts as a pattern. It's a property of analysis of what programmers do, and of course it's not possible for a programmer to act in a way that cannot be analysed :-)

Answer (score 4):

Understanding the point of a design pattern is more important than using it to the letter. Some patterns are, IMO, silly, at least in the language paradigms I'm accustomed to. IMO, a programmer who simply uses design patterns blindly and without really understanding them is a worse programmer than the one who would want to think through things themselves. But somebody who familiarizes themselves with the ideas and then decides for themselves whether they're worthwhile is likely to be a much stronger programmer than either.

That said, I have no !@#$ing idea what the point of flyweight is and I'm not ashamed to admit it. (see comments for another wikipedia entry that helped a lot)

I recommend wikipedia's entry on design patterns. It's very concisely and clearly written. Very helpful for getting an idea of why one might bother with a given design pattern or not. I personally tend to find the simplest ones the most useful and wouldn't think twice about modifying a given implementation of any pattern to suit my needs.

They're ideas, not blueprints. In some languages they're not very good ideas at all. In others, they're rightly seen as being kludges for overcoming a language's design weaknesses that might be better compensated for through less complexity. Regardless, it doesn't hurt to examine them and try to understand the challenges they're meant to overcome before deciding on your own preferred solutions.

What kinds of problems will you face? You might miss opportunities and spend more time on problems than you needed to unless you're a programming genius who already has it all figured out. It's important to maintain a critical eye of popular programming ideas but it never hurts to understand what it is people think they're solving because that will lend more clarity to your own preferred solutions/approaches.

Comment: flyweight (not flywheel). Read the first paragraph (and only the first paragraph) of the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) article and then look at [Integer.valueOf(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.valueOf%28int%29) and consider how many times this avoids creating new integers for common values.

Comment: @MichaelT And damn. That did spell it out a hell of a lot better than anything I've seen. Thanks.

Comment: The problem that I see with most of the design pattern instructions is that they try to give a big project view (the GoF book is all about writing a word processor - not a small task).  But sometimes they're applicable to much smaller (almost 'trivial') things.  7 lines of code can cleanly describe the flyweight in something that everyone uses constantly.  Much easier to understand than the big projects or contrived examples.

Comment: @MichaelT For me it's also a good example of how getting a little clarity on something is helpful to writing code in general even if that idea has no immediate use in my primary language, JavaScript, where prototypal inheritance and closures are typically used to solve that problem. Having that a-ha moment still gave me some ideas that are relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem you'll face is that you will be *reinventing the wheel*. They are called patterns because they appear often and in a predictable manner.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you follow the design patterns you might end up with a bad design. 
Design patterns are natural and you will end up using some flavour of it in your design. You will have to try really hard not to use any of the patterns. 
There is not reason to condemn design patterns, whats more important is to pick the right patterns for your needs

Answer (score -1):

You're using design patterns all the time without realizing it. A lot of standard libraries in popular languages are designed with design patterns in mind. An example is Java's `FileReader` library which is designed using the [decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Now talking about your *own* code, you're not forced to use design patterns (in most cases). A design pattern is a ["reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), meaning it will help you with writing cleaner more maintainable code so it's really up to you how much you want to avoid ending up with spaghetti code.